# remove duplicates in a text file in haskell

Tags: string, haskell, io

I am trying to **remove the duplicates from a text file** and i tried a code like following;

```
import Data.List
main = do  
    let singlewords = []
    handle <- readFile "/tmp/foo.txt" 
    singlewords = words handle
    nub singlewords
```

It gives an error of course since i am very new to haskell and i've been making some exercises but still i think i have some more time to get used to that. I would really be very appreciated for your help.

Comment: Why are you trying to overwrite `singlewords`? Remember: **Haskell does not allow mutable variables**.

Comment: That was not my tention. When i wrote like that the scope of the variables are like in Java or C++ like declaring an int and initializing it in a loop for example. But appearently that is not the case with Haskell.

Comment: Please [don't use `nub`](https://github.com/nh2/haskell-ordnub#dont-use-nub).

Comment: i know its like a nightmare :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code fixed:

```
import Data.List

main = do
    -- let singlewords = [] -- this line removed
    content <- readFile "/tmp/foo.txt"
    let singlewords = words content -- added the let keyword
    return (nub singlewords) -- added call to return
```

On the first line you write `let singlewords = []` and then later try to assign a new value to `singlewords`. This is not how we do it in Haskell, there is no need to "declare" or "define" names before we use them.

In Haskell we separate effectful computations (`IO` is one type of effectful computations) from pure computations. We bind results of effectful computations using

```
name <- computation
```

and we bind results of pure computations using

```
let name = computation
```

when in a `do`-block.

The last line in a `do`-block is what the whole block will compute, and must therefore be an effectful computation. In you example you want to return the result of a pure computation and must therefore lift the result to an effectful one, we do that using `return`.

---

To see your single words you want to output them to the console, there are a couple of functions to do so: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#g:27.

The simplest would be to output the list `singlewords` using `print`:

```
main = do
    content <- readFile "/tmp/foo.txt"
    let singlewords = nub (words content)
    print singlewords
```

Comment: That was very lightning for me, thank you so much. But may i ask how can i see the output for this from the command line? How will i see all the words without duplicates?

Comment: Oh of course! Awesome! Let me ask one last thing. Do you think the nub in here works correctly? Is my implementation doing the right thing? What are your comments? I would be very happy to hear. Thank you!

Comment: I do not know exactly what you are trying to do. If you're trying to remove all occurrences but the first of all words it does the job (it is probably not the most efficient in time and memory consumption).

Comment: Yes that is my aim and yes it is like taking forever. Do you have any other suggestion for faster processing?

Comment: If the files has many words `nub` is very slow (O(n^2)) and the whole file is kept in memory. The fast way to do this might be reading the file as a stream of words and storing only the first occurrence of a word. That is much more advanced Haskell but possible libraries are [Pipes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.7/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html) or [Conduit](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/conduit-overview)

Comment: How can i get the length in this case? I try print . length . singlewords but getting an error. Can you please help me?

Comment: `.` is function composition, you want `print (length singlewords)`.